# Is it harder to play instruments in the morning?

Tags: piano, instruments, violin

Does anyone find it harder to play instruments in the morning?  When I play piano at 8 9 10 am, fingers just feel so weird and brain is slow.  Playing violin is much tougher because all my muscles are tight and don't work properly.

Comment: I suppose something like this is dependent on a variety of factors, including what instrument you play, how long you've been awake, your age, how much sleep you had the night before, whether or not you're a morning person, and probably countless other factors I haven't thought of. I personally find myself most inspired and playing the best around 10am on a Saturday after having a cup of coffee, but I'm sure I'd have difficulties playing a tuba at 7 in the morning (ignoring the fact that I've never touched a tuba in my life)

Comment: @sxmrxzxr - bet your neighbours would have an opinion on your early morning tuba excursions too ;-)

Comment: I would vote to close this as dependent on person opinion, if I could.

Answer (score 2):

I have the opposite experience.  I find it easier to play right after I wake up, shower, and have a little coffee.  I'm on the guitar by about 6:30am.  In contrast, I find it very difficult to focus and practice in the evening.

There are different kinds of people in the world, some night owls and some early birds.  For me, morning is my most productive time.  Now creativity is another issue.  I still play in the evening and if a riff comes to me I have to work through it regardless of the time of day.  But chop building, wood-shedding, general practice has to be in the morning for me.

If your issue is muscle tightness then why?  Ask you self why you are tight in the morning.  Depending on your age this can be a sign of arthritis.  It could be too much alcohol the night before, too much salt in the diet.  There are a lot of things that can cause that.  Try changing something and see if it gets better.  Also, some stretching in the morning may help.